# How to get right picture when I click on it

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am trying to make a clickable picture and when you click on it, it is supposed to show up on the next page. 
So I have 3 templates, and when you click on template 1, it is supposed to automatically go on another page where a certain picture should be shown. If you click on template 2, pci2 should be shown. If you click on template 3, picture 3 should be shown. So can someone help me do it?

For now I have this:

```
<form action="getTemp.php" method="get">
        <center><h2>Chose your template</h2></center>

        <label>Template 1 </label>
        <img src="img/button-icons-1.png" name="slika" id="temp1" alt="template1" width="600" height="300">

        <label>Template 2 </label>
        <img src="img/button-icons-2.png" name="slika" id="temp2" alt="template1" width="600" height="300">

        <label>Template 3 </label>
        <img src="img/button-Icons-3.png" alt="template1" id="temp3" name="slika" width="600" height="300">


    </div>
```

First I need to make the clickable picture to be kind of submit.

Next I think that I need to pick up the ID of the clicked picture. Depending on the picture that was clicked, a certain picture is shown. So probably I suppose to use if-else/switch. But can someone help me how to do it?

Comment: Have a look at img, onclick, e.g. <img src="https://i.imgur.com/7KpCS0Y.jpg" onclick="window.open(this.src)">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see why this needs js or a form based on your above html.

Instead of using a form for this (as it looks like your image is the only thing you are going to pass to the next page), why not just use a link and pass a parameter on the get string (as your form is a get anyway)?

Eg

```html
<h2 style="text-align:center">Chose your template</h2>  <!-- remove center tags - they are obsolete -->:


<label>Template 1</label>
<a href="getTemp.php?template=template1"><img src="img/button-icons-1.png" name="slika" id="temp1" alt="template1" width="600" height="300"></a>

<label>Template 2</label>
<a href="getTemp.php?template=template2"><img src="img/button-icons-2.png" name="slika" id="temp2" alt="template1" width="600" height="300"></a>

<label>Template 3</label>
<a href="getTemp.php?template=template3"><img src="img/button-Icons-3.png" alt="template1" id="temp3" name="slika" width="600" height="300"></a>
```

Then in your php you can test the get var and set your image based on which template has been passed through

Comment: @MilanPoznan as long as your link looks like this: `getTemp.php?slika=template1`

Comment: This is great answer, thank you. But now I want to create picture dynamically with JS  example: var pic = document.createElement("IMG"); 
So now I have other problem, how to implement my php in this JS. But this was very helpful.

Comment: First I want to try to fix it by myself, but I will if I don't find a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Two options:

HTML only:

Make a form for each image, add an additional hidden input parameter within each form which contains the id you want to submit. Add an onclick="document.getElementById('idOfTheForm').submit()" to the image-tag.

With Javascript:

Add an hidden input parameter to your form. Add onclick="mySubmitForm(imageId)" to all of your images.

```
function mySubmitForm(imageId){
    document.getElementById('idOfHiddenInput').value = imageId;
    document.getElementById('idOfTheForm').submit();
}
```

Comment: Can you tell me what I miss here  <br>
<form action="index.php" method="get" id="form1" onclick="mySubmitForm(temp1)">
<label>Template 1 </label>
    <img src="img/button-icons-1.png" name="slika1" id="temp1" alt="template1" width="600" height="300">
           <input type="hidden" id="hid1"></input>
<script>
  function mySubmitForm(temp1){
    document.getElementById('hid1').value = "temp1";
    document.getElementById('form1').submit();
}
</script>
</form>